# Gnumeric wont convert text to lowercase

Tags: libreoffice, gnumeric

Applying function `=lower(A1)` on column and cell B1 does nothing. It justs prints as is and adds apostrophe before the function, `'=lower(A1)`.

[image]

Followed this [general advice](http://soopahman.blogspot.in/2011/12/how-to-convert-all-text-to-lowercase-in.html) for spreadsheets.

I just want to convert all the text in column A to lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do like this. 
Hope can solve your problem

[image]

Comment: Funny way to do it. But it works perfectly. Thanks for the GIF.